# iOS Swift: Best practices for starting app with an alternative UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, lifecycle

**TLDR version**: I try to push the user to a specific `UIVIewController` in an **iOS** App using **Swift** via methods to check for a saved object. If I put the push to the `VC` in the `ViewDidAppear`, it takes several seconds to fire. If I put it in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`, it throws the warning "`Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for <ProjectShare.LaunchViewController: 0x7f85a2e37520>."`

I want to know the best way to accomplish this functionality so I have a good user experience and pass Apple submission.

**Details**: I am part of a small class group working on a small software project for iOS using Swift, specifically focused on a group experience using the `MultipeerConnectivity` framework. We check for a UserInfo object persisted on the device upon launch of the app and if one is not found, we push the user to a screen to add a username and image to share with other users.

The methods for this are relatively straightforward. We check for the encoded object upon launch via the `AppDelegate`:

```
let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
if fileManager.fileExistsAtPath(self.documentsPath!) {
  var userForLoad = UserInfo.loadTheObject()
  self.defaultUser = userForLoad as UserInfo!
} else {
  self.defaultUser = nil
}
```

This works well, all of the persistence and such are working very well. The app then goes to its initial `ViewController`, here known as the `LaunchViewController:` this ViewController is the main menu for the app and will 99.9% of the time be the best starting point, and is needed immediately after creating the `UserInfo` object. If the `LaunchViewController` finds that the `appDelegate.defaultUser` object is **nil**, then I want to force the user to the `CreateUserViewController` to enter a name and capture an image.

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate
let myUserTest = appDelegate.defaultUser as UserInfo!
if myUserTest == nil {
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle())
    let destinationVC = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("CREATEUSER_VC") as CreateUserViewController!
    let presentingVC = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LAUNCHVIEW_VC") as LaunchViewController!
    destinationvVC.delegate = self
    self.presentViewController(destinationvVC, animated: false, completion: { () -> Void in
      println("Finished presenting CreateUserViewController.")
    })
}
```

This also works in that it presents the proper view controller, but the timing is tricky.

If I put this method in `viewDidLoad` or in `viewWillAppear`, it fails to fire. if I put it in `viewDidAppear`, it appears after about two seconds, which isn't a smooth user experience. if I put it in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`, i get the following warning, which I presume is a submission fail case:

```
Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for <ProjectShare.LaunchViewController: 0x7f85a2e37520>.
```

I get similar results if I use a `performSegueWithIdentifier` method.

I know that it's possible to select the initial viewController programmatically from the AppDelegate in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` (though i am not familiar with how to do it), but that seems like a poor architectural choice for something that happens exactly once in the user's relationship with the software.

Basically, looking for help making this happen smoothly for the user and in a manner that is not an apple submission fail case.

Comment: I don't quite get your question. It's perfectly valid to select the initial viewController from the AppDelegate. More over I would take that path if I were you. If the users default is != nil, why would you create a LaunchViewController if you're not going to use it?

Comment: The LaunchViewController is the primary view controller, it is the main menu controller, so the user has to get there after making a UserInfo object to start using the app. I clarified in the question. The advice  received from an instructor was that it wasn't best practice  to set the initial viewcontroller programmatically if it was almost always the one specified in the storyboard.

Comment: Well, this isn't a kind of black and white topic as many programmers don't use storyboards. I think its not bad to set it programmatically as it should be almost natural to first open the AppDelegate to see how the app starts rather than to let your self guide by storyboards names.

Comment: Thanks, that seems like a reasonable approach and its where I first intended to go, I appreciate the perspective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't seen your storyBoard but I recommend it has a `UINavigationController` so you could easily add the CreateUserVC to the parent-childen hierarchy and don't have to perform a present.

I've written this minimal example:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)

    //        var viewController: ViewController = ViewController (nibName:nil,bundle:nil)
    self.navigation = UINavigationController (rootViewController: ViewController())
    self.navigation?.addChildViewController(NewViewController())
    self.window!.rootViewController = self.navigation
    self.window!.makeKeyAndVisible()
    return true
}
```

of course you should check for the UserDefaults before adding the CreateUserVC as a childViewController. But if you do add it, the app will start with the CreateUserVC presented and the Back button on its navigation that leads to LaunchVC.

NOTE: You can have your navigation hidden if your app doesn't show one.

Comment: I didn't realize that a nav controller could be hidden, we definitely don't want to have one for this project for various reasons. I'll have to talk that over with the team, I have been focused on the data models for the project and less on the view controllers so I am not sure how it would affect their work. I appreciate the answer.